# Magento 1.9 getting Authorize.Net return values

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, authorize.net

I am having difficulty with getting some specific values from Authorize.Net. I am looking for the Transaction ID and the Credit Card Name (Visa, MasterCard, etc). I have tried loading the Transaction ID by using `$order->getTransactionId()` with no success. Also using `$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCcType();` for the card name. My code runs after a sales_order_place_after event in an observer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try your code with `sales_order_save_commit_after` observer?

Comment: @Charlie...I changed the observer to your suggestion and no change. Could it be because I am posting to the test Authorize.Net? From some documentation at [link]http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html[/link], getTransactionId() doesn't seem to be a function. In the response array from Authorize.net card_type is left blank...probably due to it being a test. Any ideas?